# Multiplication Game

Tags: php, html

The Game Rules :-

1- When the user first comes to the site a new expression is provided.

2- The user enters the guess and submits the form using the “Check” button.

3- The program checks the answer and if wrong provides a proper message and allows the user to keep guessing the same expression.

4- If the user guesses the result, then a new expression is provided.
The Game problem I face it is :-

1- Never get true result.

2- The $expression not  allows the user to keep guessing the same expression.

Note: 
I use random number between 1 and 12 inclusive function rand(1, 12)

```
     <?php
        $a= rand(1, 12);

        $b= rand(1, 12);

        $message;

        $answer = null;

        $expression = $a ." X ".$b ;

        if (!isset($_POST['guess'])) {

             $message = "Welcome to the Multiplication progarm<br/>";

        }

        elseif ($_POST['guess'] == $a*$b) { // matches!

             $message = $a ." X ".$b." = ".$a*$b." is Correct!<br/> Now try the new expression";

             $answer = $_POST['guess'];

        }

        elseif ($_POST['guess'] != $a*$b) { // some other condition

             $message = $_POST['guess']." is Wrong!";

             $answer = $_POST['guess'];

        }

        ?>


        <html>
         <body> 
        <h2><?php echo $message; ?></h2>
         <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
         <input type="hidden" name="answer" value="<?php echo $answer;?>"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="expression" value="<?php echo $expression;?>">
     What is the value of the following multiplication expression: 
<br>
        <br>
     <?php echo $expression; ?><input type="text" name="guess"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Check">
         </form> 
        </body> 
        </html>
```

Comment: On each page load you reset the values of `$a`/`$b`, and then check `elseif ($_POST['guess'] == $a*$b)`. You either need to check `elseif ($_POST['guess'] == $_POST['answer'])` **OR** save the answer in a `$_SESSION`. Similar issue for #2, as you either need to use `$_POST['expression']` or again save to a `$_SESSION`.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php and try to learn the basics on your own as @Sean has already explained.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
    session_start();//you must use session in the first 
    $_SESSION['expression'] = $_POST['expression'];//define session to make the expression in the same value. 
    $_SESSION['answer'] = $_POST['answer'];//define session to make the answer in the same value.
    elseif ($_POST['guess'] == $a*$b) { // matches!
         $message = $a ." X ".$b." = ".$a*$b." is Correct!<br/> Now try the new expression";
         session_destroy();//you must use this to stop session to produces new expression.
```

Comment: This still has the same issue of the OP as you still have `elseif ($_POST['guess'] == $a*$b)`, so it is comparing to the new `$a`&`$b` instead of `$_POST['answer']` or `$_SESSION['answer']`